# How to compute the average of specific tuple integers within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary in the form:

```
students = {student_1: {'Assignments': [('Assignment_1', 3),
                                        ('Assignment_2', 4),
                                        ('Assignment_3', 2),
                                        ('Assignment_4', 4)],
                        'first_name': 'Alex',
                        'id': 1009,
                        'last_name': 'Robertson'},
            student_2: {'Assignments': [('Assignment_1', 2),
                                        ('Assignment_2', 1),
                                        ('Assignment_3', 2),
                                        ('Assignment_4', 4)],
                        'first_name': 'Dave',
                        'id': 2009,
                        'last_name': 'Robertson'},
            student_3: {'Assignments': [('Assignment_1', 4),
                                        ('Assignment_2', 4),
                                        ('Assignment_3', 4),
                                        ('Assignment_4', 0)],
                        'first_name': 'Carter',
                         'id': 3109,
                         'last_name': 'Smith'}}
```

And I need to create a function that takes the average score of all `"Assignments"`. For instance, in `("Assignment_1", 4)`, `4` is the assignment score. How do I select just those values to do the calculation?

Comment: It seems like you could drop the "Assignment_n" from the tuples in the list since the order is already preserved. Then you could just look up the score with `students[student_id]["Assignments"][assignment_number]`

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58359214/edit) your question to provide code or just explain how you think the algorithm should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of the scores for each student in the `students` dictionary using something called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Computing the average from it should be fairly easy.

```
for student in students.values():
    scores = [score for (assignment, score) in student['Assignments']]
    average = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to solve it in Python 3. Use `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

# Assuming you have a dictionary students
students = {'student_1': {'Assignments': [('Assignment_1', 3),
                             ('Assignment_2', 4),
                             ('Assignment_3', 2),
                             ('Assignment_4', 4)],
                          'first_name': 'Alex',
                          'id': 1009,
                          'last_name': 'Robertson'},
            'student_2': {'Assignments': [('Assignment_1', 2),
                             ('Assignment_2', 1),
                             ('Assignment_3', 2),
                             ('Assignment_4', 4)],
                          'first_name': 'Dave',
                          'id': 2009,
                          'last_name': 'Robertson'}}

# Iterate over dictionary's values
for v in students.values():
    # lambda to calculate average - just a helper
    l = lambda lst: reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, lst) / len(lst)

    # Comprehend the values from tuples in dictionary
    # - you know the values are at index 1 of the tuple
    values = [i[1] for i in v[list(v.keys())[0]]]

    # Calculate the average for extracted values
    average = l(values)

    # Round to second digit
    r = round(average, 2)
    # Output the result
    print("Average {}".format(r))
```

You can further modify it to closer match your needs.